# Python Pandas: How to use "resample" together with "idxmin"?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe with a pandas datetime index.

```
    TIMESTAMP          water
2020-06-24 13:50:00   -0.5
2020-06-24 14:00:00   -0.6
2020-06-24 14:10:00   -0.7
2020-06-24 14:30:00   -0.5
2020-06-24 14:40:00   -0.8
...
```

I want to get the index of the daily minimum value. This is my approach which is not working:

```
water_daily_min_index = df['water'].resample('D').idxmin()
```

How can I solve this without creating a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) like alternative to `resample`:

```
water_daily_min_index = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['water'].idxmin()
print (water_daily_min_index)
TIMESTAMP
2020-06-24   2020-06-24 14:40:00
Freq: D, Name: water, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```